# Setting up horizontal forms and appending buttons

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a form:
http://fiddle.jshell.net/eJ2kS/
I want to have the label and text input on one line and the button to be appended to the text input but the documentation is a little vague about appending buttons:
http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/base-css.html#forms

Comment: Maybe create a demo of your form on http://fiddle.jshell.net posting your form code and your css code.

Comment: We need to know your CSS code.

Comment: @sharethis It's just default twitter bootstrap, no custom css, I put the full bootstrap css in the jsfiddle

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Do you opt for THIS?[image]

If so, then the code shall be...

```
<form id="signup" method="post" action="/signup" class="form-horizontal">
                    <legend>Sign Up</legend>

                    <div class="control-group">
                        <label for="appendedInputButton" class="control-label">User Name</label>
                        <div class="controls">
                          <div class="input-append">
                            <input type="text" size="16" id="appendedInputButton" class="span2"><button type="button" class="btn">Check Availabilty</button>
                          </div>
                        </div>
                     </div>
                </fieldset>
            </form>
```

I think I've updated your fiddle... [RIGHT HERE.](http://fiddle.jshell.net/eJ2kS/12/)

Comment: thank you, I didn't realise the input and button have to be on the same line

Answer (score 0):

You have to override the style like the following. Note that this isn't a solution about using your framework.

```
.control-group, .btn, .control-group label, .controls{ float:left !important; }
.controls{ margin:0 1em !important; }
.control-group{ margin:0 !important; }
label{ margin:5px !important; }
```

I hope this is what you want. It floates all needed elements to the left and corrects some margins. That's all. The `!important` is to force overriding the old value from your framework.

Here is your updated fiddle: http://fiddle.jshell.net/eJ2kS/5/